# jwplayer flashvars get direct stream link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Okay so ive tried to get this working for the past 4 hours but no luck.

Basically i want to get the direct link of this video using PHP.

http://vidbull.com/embed-601grwgxux0p-720x405.html

When you click play on the video and check the network tab in chrome/IE/Firebug etc it will output the video url with a unique token.

Is there anyway to scrape the link with PHP to get this URL with the unique token?

Comment: VidBull has probably done something with their embed to protect leeching. Are you actually trying to embed the JW Player, or just trying to get their video?

Comment: Id like to get the video link

Comment: No one is going to help you steal someone else's content. Flagged.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically asking how to steal videos.

Comment: Im not stealing content.. i just wanted to figure out if it was possible so i can protect my content..